# Restart docker compose with a different command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've an application running on a server, but somehow the server rebooted but some docker services could restart, another not.

**docker-compose ps:**

```sh
    Name                   Command                 State                          Ports                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
elasticsearch   /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up           0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp
kibana          sh -c ./bin/kibana-plugin  ...   Restarting                                                 
logstash        /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up           5044/tcp, 9600/tcp
```

If I try to see the logs of kibana by **docker kibana ps:**

```sh
Plugin kbn_radar already exists, please remove before installing a new version
Found previous install attempt. Deleting...
Attempting to transfer from file:///usr/share/kibana/config/kbn_radar.zip
Transferring 3686700 bytes....................
Transfer complete
Retrieving metadata from plugin archive
Extracting plugin archive
```

The problem is: kbn_radar takes a long time to restart, so I want to restart the kibana service without needing to restart the other applications. I've tried to change my .yml file where I've run the commands to start de plugins:

```js
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.0
    command: 
    - sh 
    - -c
    - './bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/kbn_radar.zip && ./bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip && exec /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker'
```

So at the end, my docker compose was:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```js
version: "3"

networks:
  elasticsearch-net-624:

services:
  elasticsearch-products-624-service:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    networks:
    - elasticsearch-net-624
    ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
    expose:
    - "9200"
    volumes:
    - /home/docker/elastic.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    - /home/docker/elastic-certificates.p12:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-certificates.p12
    - /docker/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - /docker/elastic/data/snapshots:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshots

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.0
    command: 
    - sh 
    - -c
    - 'exec /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker'
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    hostname: kibana
    networks:
    - elasticsearch-net-624
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=kibana.localhost
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
    - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
    - XPACK_GRAPH_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_WATCHER_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_ML_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED
    ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    expose:
    - "5601"
    links:
    - elasticsearch-products-624-service
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch-products-624-service
    volumes:
    - /home/docker/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    - /home/docker/ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip:/usr/share/kibana/config/ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip
    - /home/docker/kbn_radar.zip:/usr/share/kibana/config/kbn_radar.zip 
    - /home/morpheus/docker/dashboard_app.js:/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/kibana/public/dashboard/dashboard_app.js

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.8.0
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/docker/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
```

Finally I've tried to restart the service:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-kibana.yml restart kibana
```

But, the service keeps trying to restart the plugins and if I run docker-compose ps, the command continues "sh -c ./bin/kibana-plugin  ..."

How could I restart docker service with another command? Or restart my service without restarting the plugin that already exists?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you clarify? `so I want to restart the kibana service without needing to restart the other applications` this is exactly what's going on. `kibana` is restarting while `logstash` and `elasticsearch` are up and running.

Comment: Exactly. But, when I restart kibana I've got the error: `Plugin kbn_radar already exists, please remove before installing a new version`. I want now restart kibana with another command: `exec /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker` instead of `./bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/kbn_radar.zip && ./bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip && exec /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker` that was at the first time.

Comment: @Vítor Resende if any of the answers solved your issue please accept the appropriate answer to share the resolution with the community. If not please provide further information or share your own solution. Thank you

Comment: Hi @ClemensKaserer, you are right, it's important to feedback the community. I've tried the eez0 solution firstly, but as he explains, change something after starting a  docker compose application will not take effect unless you restart the whole context. So, what happened was that I've needed to restart my application (that was what I didn't want to). So I don't know if my question has a solution. I haven't tried your solution cause my application is in production. I'll try some way to test and come back here with another feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a build for your plugin and not do everything at the container start.

A simple dockerfile to fix your issue would look somewhat like this

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.0
COPY ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip kbn_radar.zip /usr/share/kibana/config/
RUN ./bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/kbn_radar.zip && 
    ./bin/kibana-plugin install file:///usr/share/kibana/config/ob-kb-funnel-6.8.zip
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker
```

Next you would need to use docker-compose to build your image. We can do that by updating your service definition

```
kibana:
    build: 
      context: ./kibana
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    hostname: kibana
    networks:
    - elasticsearch-net-624
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=kibana.localhost
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
    - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
    - XPACK_GRAPH_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_WATCHER_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_ML_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=true
    - XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED
    ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    expose:
    - "5601"
    links:
    - elasticsearch-products-624-service
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch-products-624-service
    volumes:
    - /home/docker/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    - /home/morpheus/docker/dashboard_app.js:/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/kibana/public/dashboard/dashboard_app.js
```

As you can see in the service definition we replaced image with build. We assume that your `Dockerfile` for kibana resides in a folder called `kibana` and also contains your plugin zip files.

next you can run `docker-compose build` and it will build you the required images for your compose stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run a `docker-compose` or a `docker stack`, a context is created with all the initial data. If  you later change this data, for example the `command` in your case, it will not take effect unless you restart the whole context, that is, unless you bring down and up again the `docker-compose` or `stack`.

However, you might try your luck with the following:

1. Edit the compose with the command you want to run now.
2. Remove the `kibana` container at all. I mean, don't try to restart kibana with `docker-compose`, but remove the container. `docker rm -f dir_kibana`
3. Run `docker-compose up` again. It should detect that `kibana` is missing and run it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, it restarted the application but I think, when I removed the service with `docker rm -f dir_kibana`, the plugins were removed too. Anyway, thanks for your answer and time to answer me.